# Two namespaces in xml while exporting from excel to xml

Tags: xml, excel

I have an xml file which looks like this;
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iaapi:Project xmlns:iaapi="http://www.ibm.com/investigate/api/iaapi" name="IA Quickstart">
  <DataRuleDefinitions>
    <DataRuleDefinition name="CanadaSinMatchesRegex">
      <ExecutableRules>
        <ExecutableRule folder="All" name="CanadaSinMatchesRegex2" excludeDuplicates="false">
          <description></description>
          <LongDescription></LongDescription>
          <BoundExpression>EDW.CCAS.LCNDWT1.DW.&quot;CCAS_ENT_BRWR_STG&quot;.I_OFFCR_EMP_ID MATCHES_REGEX   '^([0-79]\\d{2})([ \\-\\.]?)(\\d{3})\\2(\\d{3})$'</BoundExpression>
          <OutputDefinition type="FailingRecords">
            <OutputColumn name="sin" type="variable" value="sin"/>
          </OutputDefinition>
          <Bindings>
            <Binding var="sin">
              <Column name="&quot;EDW.CCAS&quot;.LCNDWT1.DW.CCAS_ENT_BRWR_STG.I_OFFCR_EMP_ID"/>
            </Binding>
          </Bindings>
        </ExecutableRule>
      </ExecutableRules>
    </DataRuleDefinition>
  </DataRuleDefinitions>
</iaapi:Project>
```

```

I did convert this xml file into excel using the import function in excel. Then when I try to export back to xml, I get the following xml output;

```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <ns1:Project  xmlns:ns1="http://www.ibm.com/investigate/api/iaapi"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="IA Quickstart">
    <DataRuleDefinitions>
        <DataRuleDefinition name="CanadaSinMatchesRegex">
            <ExecutableRules>
                <ExecutableRule folder="All" name="CanadaSinMatchesRegex2"      excludeDuplicates="false">
                    <BoundExpression>EDW.CCAS.LCNDWT1.DW."CCAS_ENT_BRWR_STG".I_OFFCR_EMP_ID MATCHES_REGEX   '^([0-79]\\d{2})([ \\-\\.]?)(\\d{3})\\2(\\d{3})$'</BoundExpression>
                    <OutputDefinition type="FailingRecords">
                        <OutputColumn name="sin" type="variable" value="sin"/>
                    </OutputDefinition>
                    <Bindings>
                        <Binding var="sin">
                            <Column name="&quot;EDW.CCAS&quot;.LCNDWT1.DW.CCAS_ENT_BRWR_STG.I_OFFCR_EMP_ID"/>
                        </Binding>
                    </Bindings>
                </ExecutableRule>
            </ExecutableRules>
        </DataRuleDefinition>
    </DataRuleDefinitions>
     </ns1:Project>
```

```
Can I get help in understanding why do we get two namespaces after being exported from excel? Help is greatly appreciated. thanks